# Is it possible to install office 365 on ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS? If yes, Kindly guide me

Tags: 20.04, office365

I tried running the following command:
$ sudo snap install unofficial-webapp-office

The response i got:
error: snap "unofficial-webapp-office" not found

Comment: did you first run `sudo apt update` [reference](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-micrtosoft-office-365-on-ubuntu-20-04-linux-without-wine/)

Comment: Yes, all packages were up-to-date.

Answer (score 3):

Possible alternative would be https://snapcraft.io/office365webdesktop which is in Beta stage now. To install run:

```
snap install --beta office365webdesktop
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  You can just go the the Github site of the person who made it and download the source code there: https://github.com/sirredbeard/unofficial-webapp-office